# Converting a iterable of ordered dict's to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am iterating over OrderedDict's and want to store them as pandas dataframe. Is there a commend to do that? Currently, the code is:

One row in `res` looks like this:

`OrderedDict([('field_id', 1), ('date', datetime.date(2016, 1, 3)), ('temp', 30.08), ('norm_temperature', None), ('prcp', 12.8848107785339), ('abcd', 0.0), ('efgh', None), ('ijkl', 1.38), ('lmno', None), ('poq', None)])`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

I get this error: `*** TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator`

How do I store this iterator over ordered dict's into a dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `res` is like this:

```
res = iter([row1,row2,...])
```

You can do it this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(*[res])
```

Comment: Cheers, mate! Happy coding to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(res)
```